# Почему не показывает результат работы? Задача на фильтрование текста

Tags: java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.*;


public class mainBot {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System. in ));
        BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System. in ));

        String text = reader.readLine();
        String word = reader1.readLine();

        TextSort textSort = new TextSort(text);
        textSort.sortText(word);

    }

    static class TextSort {
        ArrayList < String > littleList = new ArrayList < > ();
        String[] strings;

        public TextSort(String text) {
            strings = text.split(".");
        }

        void sortText(String word) {
            word = word.toLowerCase();
            for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
                strings[i] = strings[i].toLowerCase();
                if (strings[i].contains(word)) littleList.add(strings[i]);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < littleList.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(littleList.get(i));
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: а как вы это используете? какие данные задаете?

Comment: считывание строк через BufferedReader

Comment: использование этого класса покажите. так как не понялно чему равна `text` и `word` в вашем случае

Comment: вроде бы все должно работать, но не получается(

Comment: Два `BufferedReader` - излишне, чтобы прочитать две строки, можно вызвать `reader.readLine()` для каждой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`split(String regex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) принимает регулярное выражение. По точке разделять нужно так:

```
strings = text.split("\\.");
```